# create links to bot_commands and pass parameters

Tags: node.js, telegram

When using the telegram API (in my case using telebot:https://github.com/kosmodrey/telebot)

How can link to a bot_command with a parameter ?

For example i want a bot that shows information about some fruits and i have
`['apples','pears','bananas']`

i can do `/show [fruit]` to show details about each fruit and `/list` to
show a list of all fruits.

When i do `/list` i want to show it like this:

> You currently have 3 fruit:
>
> APPLES PEARS BANANAS

However i want these to be clickable and once the user clicks a fruitname, he
will be directed to `/show [clicked fruit]`.

i tried with a normal `a href` in `{ parse_mode : HTML }` but that doesn't
seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use inline buttons. They work the way you described. For example:

```
var options = {
  reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
    inline_keyboard: [
      [
        {text: 'button 1', callback_data: '1'},
        {text: 'button 2', callback_data: '2'},
        {text: 'button 3', callback_data: '3'},
      ],
    ]
  })
};

bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Pick action:', options);
```

You can think of them as anchor tags. They appear along with the text in chat window, and scroll with the text, but you can click on them. Non-inline buttons are more like a permanent menu.

Example above is using [this](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api) library.